# Laravel Framework 5.7.27 custom method return blank page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have this issue of getting a blank page in Laravel and I don't know where I go wrong.

Here is my code sample: view **maintenance/index.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('maintenance.update_request')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     .....
```

and in  Controller **MaintenanceController.php** I create custom method `update_request`

```
public function update_request(Request $request) {
    dd($request);
}
```

then web.php (route)

```
Route::post('maintenance/update_request', 'MaintenanceController@update_request')->name('maintenance.update_request');
Route::resource('maintenance', 'MaintenanceController');
```

but when i click submit button i get **blank page** ....public/maintenance/update_request

Comment: if you are using put in form you should Change your Route post to any it will work

Comment: Route::any('maintenance/update_request', 'MaintenanceController@update_request')->name('maintenance.update_request');

Comment: remove '.' between 'maintenance.update_request' and try again.

Comment: Try to put the "maintenance/update_request" route, after Route::resource('maintenance', 'MaintenanceController');

Comment: thank you guys it work after change Route::post to Route::put

Answer (score 5):

Your route method should be `put` because you are submitting your form on `put` request.

```
Route::put('maintenance/update_request', 'MaintenanceController@update_request')->name('maintenance.update_request');

OR

Route::put('maintenance/update_request', ['as'=>'maintenance.update_request','uses'=>'MaintenanceController@update_request']);
```